# angular ui-grid - dynamically change the css style on page size is change

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How dynamically change the css style when page size is changed in angular ui-grid? .

My  use case is , I want to show edit/delete in grey color based on user type logged in. Based on "row.entity.isEditable" flag from the server side ng-disabled is set and style is applied based on disabled state.

This works perfectly fine with all rows(say 15) displayed in single shot. If we change the page size to 5 or 10 then the style is not rendered properly. Hence we are seeing inappropriate grey/colored link in UI.

**Please let me know , how to get this resolved. Or let us know if you have any other approach for this?**

```
id  name    actions
1   AAA     view edit delete 
2   BBB     view edit delete 
3   CCC     view edit delete 
4   DDD     view edit delete 

  <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content box-table">
            <div ui-grid="gridUsers" ui-grid-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

<style type="text/css">
    a[disabled="disabled"] {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    span[disabled="disabled"] {
        color: #a8a8a8 !important
    }
</style>

  $scope.gridUsers = {
            paginationPageSizes: [15, 30, 45],
            paginationPageSize: 15,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            data: $scope.users,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'id', displayName: 'Id', width: '20%'},
                { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', width: '25%', enableFiltering: true},
                { name: 'Actions', displayName: 'Actions', width: '55%', cellTemplate:
                '<div class="grid-action-cell action-btns">'+
                '<span class="btn-small"><span style="color:#214c77;">view</span> </a>' +
                '<a ng-disabled={{!row.entity.isEditable}} ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(row.entity.id)" class="btn-small btn-link"><span ng-disabled={{!row.entity.isEditable}} style="color:#80bb41;">edit</span> </a>' +
                '<a ng-disabled={{!row.entity.isEditable}} ng-click="grid.appScope.delete(row.entity.id)" class="btn-small btn-link"> <span ng-disabled={{!row.entity.isEditable}} style="color:#e15829;">delete</span> </a>' 
                '</div>'}
            ]
        };


 Service.GetAllUsers(function (response) {
            if (response.length != 0) {
                $scope.users = response;
                $scope.gridUsers.data = $scope.users;
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with my custom css as well but solved it by explicitly notify the grid that a data change has occurred with the notifyDataChange event.

```
//use onRegisterApi to handle grid events
$scope.gridUsers.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

    //register an event for pagination
    gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {

        //call notifyDataChange to tell the grid that data has changed
        gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL);
    });
};
```

Comment: What is "uiGridConstants" here ?

Comment: @JavaUser The uiGridConstants is a object which contains all the constants related to the ui-grid. Docs here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.service:uiGridConstants